# Как решить проблему с реляциями при запросе на получение нескольких записей в doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine2

Есть следующие таблицы: countries, visas, embassies.
(у одной country может быть множество visas и embassies).

я делаю запрос, который получает несколько записей countries:

```php
       $currencies = $this->entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from(Country::class, 'c')
            ->setMaxResults($condition->first)
            ->setFirstResult($condition->offset)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

ок, все работает.

далее когда мы работаем с $currencies в цикле и дергаем visas и embassises, то натыкаемся на проблему с запросами N+1. В моем случае это 200+ запросов за раз.

Пробуем решить проблему с join:

```php
       $currencies = $this->entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from(Country::class, 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.visas', 'cv')
            ->addSelect('cv')
            ->leftJoin('c.embassies', 'ce')
            ->addSelect('ce')
            ->setMaxResults($condition->first)
            ->setFirstResult($condition->offset)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

итак это решает проблему с N+1, превращая 200+ запросов в 4, но появляется следующая проблема:

к примеру у нас в таблице (или найдена по условию запроса) 1 запись country, но у этой country, к примеру 3 visas и 5 embassises записей в базе.

Так вот в случае использования join, при условии, что найдена 1 country реляции на visas и embassises будет возвращать так-же 1 запись (не в зависимости от того, что их может быть больше по факту).

Такое поведение происходит из-за leftJoin, и с одной стороны это 200+ запросов. с другой стороны неполная отдача данных в случае, если записей countries  меньше, чем возможных реляций.

Как можно решить эту проблему?